# How can I select the name data inside this a tag using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to coding; I just started 4 months ago. I'm using beautiful soup on python to try and extract information about graphics cards.

Here is my issue, when I try to get the price of a graphics card it gives me the **wrong information**. A card that should cost 379.99 on the website says in the terminal that the price is only 79.99. All of the prices are the wrong numbers in the terminal. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
from bs4.element import PageElement
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
print("loading website")
webpage_response = requests.get("https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&NTX=mode+MatchPartial&NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&NTK=all&page=1&cat=Computer-Parts-:-MicroCenter")


print("done loading website")
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
#print(soup)
PageContent = soup.find(attrs={"id": "topPagination"})
MarginLeft = PageContent.find(attrs = {"class": "pages inline"})
CurrentPage = MarginLeft.find(attrs = {"class": "current"})


#helps get graphics card data
Content = soup.find("article", {"id": "productGrid"})
ULinContent = Content.find("ul")
Pwrapper = ULinContent.find_all(attrs={"class": "product_wrapper"})
#print(Pwrapper)
#print(Content)
#print(ULinContent)

CurrentPage = CurrentPage.get_text()
print("We are on page " + CurrentPage)
#print(MarginLeft)
#find number of web pages, then add all the way 
#up to that so we can get all of data
#NumberOfPages = PageContent.find(attrs={"class": "btn"})
#print(NumberOfPages)


#get prices of all rtx cards
prices = []
names = []

links = []
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    links.append(link.get("href"))
print(links)

def GetCardDetails(prices, Pwrapper, names):
    for Pwrapp in Pwrapper:
        CheckBox = Pwrapp.find(attrs={"class": "checkbox"})
        CheckBoxText = CheckBox.get_text()
        
        #clean card name, the 15 and -11 index cleans compare from html
        CheckBoxClean = CheckBoxText[15:-11]
        #print(CheckBoxClean)
        names.append(CheckBoxClean)
        
        #price
        Card_Price = Pwrapp.find_all(attrs={"itemprop": "price"})
        print(Card_Price)
        print(Pwrapp.get_text())
        for price in Card_Price:
            GetText = price.get_text()
            prices.append(GetText)
            print(GetText)


    DicPrName = {"Graphics_Card_Name": names, "Prices": prices}
    #MAKE GRAPH
    data_frame2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DicPrName)
    print(
        )
    plt.hist(prices)
    plt.show()
    print(DicPrName)

GetCardDetails(prices, Pwrapper, names)
#print(prices)
#print(names)

#average and graph them, get their data









#find the variabels to store using dict and table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css attribute = value selectors as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

print("loading website")
webpage_response = requests.get("https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?N=4294966998&NTX=mode+MatchPartial&NTT=rtx+graphics+cards&NTK=all&page=1&cat=Computer-Parts-:-MicroCenter",
                                headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})


print("done loading website")
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
print({i['data-name']:i['data-price'] for i in soup.select('[data-price]')})
```